# struct and variable looping C language

Tags: c, loops, variables, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Car {
  char brand[50];
  char model[50];
  int year;
};

int main() {
  struct Car car1 = {"BMW", "X5", 1999};
  struct Car car2 = {"Ford", "Mustang", 1969};
  struct Car car3 = {"Toyota", "Corolla", 2011};

  printf("%s %s %d\n", car1.brand, car1.model, car1.year);
  printf("%s %s %d\n", car2.brand, car2.model, car2.year);
  printf("%s %s %d\n", car3.brand, car3.model, car3.year);

  return 0;
}

/*
BMW X5 1999
Ford Mustang 1969
Toyota Corolla 2011
*/
```

Here the struct only has 3 variables (car1, car2, car3). But if it had numerous cars, how could I make this same code (print all values) using a loop?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over an array of `Car`s or the members of a `Car`?  If it's the latter, then it's not possible in C.

Comment: maybe I expressed myself wrong (my english is not very good), but what I wanted was the same output.. but with a for or while loop, as it would be useful in case I have more cars, so I don't have to use 100 , 200, 1000 print commands...

Comment: You want an array of `Car`s

Comment: and how would you do it? could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an array of `Car`s, something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Car {
  char brand[50];
  char model[50];
  int year;
};

int main() {
    struct Car cars[] = {
        {"BMW", "X5", 1999},
        {"Ford", "Mustang", 1969},
        {"Toyota", "Corolla", 2011},
        {"Mercedes", "C197", 2010 }
    };

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(cars)/sizeof(cars[0]); ++i) {

        printf("%s %s %d\n", cars[i].brand, cars[i].model, cars[i].year);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of `struct Car`.

It works pretty much the same as any other array in with the difference that each element now has extra fields, the ones on your struct.

Here is an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

struct Car {
  char brand[50];
  char model[50];
  int year;
};


int main(void) {
    struct Car cars[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        // Initialize
        strcpy(cars[i].brand, "BMW"); // or any other brand
        strcpy(cars[i].model, "X5");

        cars[i].year = 1999;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        // Print
        printf("Car %d:\n", i + 1);
        printf("%s %s %d\n", cars[i].brand, cars[i].model, cars[i].year);
    }

    return 0;
}
```